# hive on spark - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: apache-spark, hive

i want to run 'select count(*) from test' on 'hive on spark' through beeline, but it crashed.

```
INFO client.SparkClientUtilities: Added jar[file:/home/.../hive/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar] to classpath
INFO client.RemoteDriver: Failed to run job 41dc814c-deb7-4743-9b6a-b6cace2eae19
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 
Serialization trace: 
dummyOps (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ReduceWork) left (org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair) edgeProperties (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.SparkWork)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:626)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:648)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:605)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:126)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:17)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:648)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:605)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.KryoSerializer.deserialize(KryoSerializer.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.RemoteHiveSparkClient$JobStatusJob.call(RemoteHiveSparkClient.java:235)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver$JobWrapper.call(RemoteDriver.java:366)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver$JobWrapper.call(RemoteDriver.java:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.setGenerics(MapSerializer.java:53)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:604)
    ... 19 more
```

hive on spark configuration is:

```
set spark.home=/home/.../spark;

set hive.execution.engine=spark;

set spark.master=yarn;

set spark.eventLog.enabled=true;

set spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://...:9000/user/.../spark-history-server-records;

set spark.executor.memory=1024m;

set spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer;
```

and what's worse, when i change KryoSerializer to JavaSerializer, this issue still exists.

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this. I am stuck on the same exception. Thanks for your help

Comment: I guess that there exists some differences between tables of hive and spark, and I had gave up hive on spark, use spark sql directly, hive can be a data source of spark sql.